# How to profile a web service?

Tags: json, rest, node.js, mongodb

I'm currently developing an practice application in node.js. This applications consists of a JSON REST web service which allows two services.

- Insert log (a PUT request to /log, with the message to log)
- Last 100 logs (a GET request to /log, that returns the latest 100 logs)

The current stack is formed by a node.js server that has the application logic and a mongodb database that takes care of the persistence. To offer the JSON REST web services I'm using the [node-restify](https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify) module.

I'm currently executing some stress tests using apache bench (using 5000 requests with a concurrency of 10) and get the following results:

```
Execute stress tests

1) Insert log
Requests per second:    754.80 [#/sec] (mean)

2) Last 100 logs
Requests per second:    110.37 [#/sec] (mean)
```

I'm surprised of the difference there is in performance, the query I'm executing uses an index. Interestingly enough it seems that the JSON output generation seems to get all the time on deeper tests I have performed.

**Can node applications be profiled in detail?**

**Is this behaviour normal? Retrieving data takes so much more than inserting data?**

**EDIT:**

*Full test information*

```
1) Insert log
    This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)


Server Software:        log-server
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            3010

Document Path:          /log
Document Length:        0 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   6.502 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      2240634 bytes
Total PUT:              935000
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    768.99 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       13.004 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.300 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          336.53 [Kbytes/sec] received
                        140.43 kb/s sent
                        476.96 kb/s total

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       3
Processing:     6   13   3.9     12      39
Waiting:        6   12   3.9     11      39
Total:          6   13   3.9     12      39

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     12
  66%     12
  75%     12
  80%     13
  90%     15
  95%     24
  98%     26
  99%     30
 100%     39 (longest request)

2) Last 100 logs
    This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)


Server Software:        log-server
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            3010

Document Path:          /log
Document Length:        4601 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   46.528 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      25620233 bytes
HTML transferred:       23005000 bytes
Requests per second:    107.46 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       93.057 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       9.306 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          537.73 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       1
Processing:    28   93  16.4     92     166
Waiting:       26   85  18.0     86     161
Total:         29   93  16.4     92     166

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     92
  66%     97
  75%    101
  80%    104
  90%    113
  95%    121
  98%    131
  99%    137
 100%    166 (longest request)
```

*Retrieving data from the database*

To query the database I use the [mongoosejs](http://mongoosejs.com/) module. The log schema is defined as:

```
{
    date: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now, index: true }, 
    message: String
}
```

and the query I execute is the following:

```
Log.find({}, ['message']).sort('date', -1).limit(100)
```

Comment: How much data is contained in each log? The difference in performance may just be because of the amount of data that is returned on the GET.  Also, is the retrieve operation using an index on the log date?

Comment: @beny23 I have added the full log from apache bench so you can analyse the amount of data I'm sending. The index is indeed on the log date.

Comment: Personally I think that looks normal, after all you're inserting 1 object and are retrieving 100 objects each time, so while reading is faster than writing, you're reading a lot more than you're writing.  One thing I find a bit puzzling.  The document length for the GET is only 301 bytes, does that mean that each log entry only has 3 bytes?

Comment: @beny23 You were right, the log messages were not being sent correctly and the logs were being inserted empty, so its log entry was "{}," ^^. Corrected the error, launched the tests and updated the results

Answer (score 0):

> Can node applications be profiled in detail?

Yes. Use `node --prof app.js` to create a `v8.log`, then use `linux-tick-processor`, `mac-tick-processor` or `windows-tick-processor.bat` (in `deps/v8/tools` in the node src directory) to interpret the log. You have to build `d8` in `deps/v8` to be able to run the tick processor.

Here's how I do it on my machine:

```
apt-get install scons
cd ~/development/external/node-0.6.12/deps/v8
scons arch=x64 d8
cd ~/development/projects/foo
node --prof app.js
D8_PATH=~/development/external/node-0.6.12/deps/v8 ~/development/external/node-0.6.12/deps/v8/tools/linux-tick-processor > profile.log
```

There are also a few tools to make this easier, including [node-profiler](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler) and [v8-profiler](https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler) (with [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector)).

Regarding your other question, I would like some more information on how you fetch your data from Mongo, and what the data looks like (I agree with beny23 that it looks like a suspiciously low amount of data).

Comment: I use the mongoose module to query mongodb, the query is quite straight forward: Log.find({}, ['message']).sort('date', -1).limit(100)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest taking a look at the DTrace support of Restify. It will likely become your best friend when profiling.

http://mcavage.github.com/node-restify/#DTrace

Comment: can DTrace be installed on ubuntu?

Comment: Yes there is a Linux port, although I have not personally tried it (yet) this looks like the best source of info for installing in Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60940/how-do-i-install-dtrace